# Calculating limit for sequence that tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How am I supposed to calculate this? Please help, I don't know where to start.

cosine values are between -1 and 1 right? So how am I supposed to use that exactly?
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (\cos n - 1)n^2
$$

Do I just calculate brackets individually and multiply results?

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{3n+2}{5n+2}\right)^n \cdot \left(\frac{5n+3}{3n+1}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

for the first one, note that $n^2$ will grow to $\infty$ but $\cos n-1$ will keep changing the sign indefinitely.

for the second one, you can transform it to this:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\left(\frac{5n+3}{5n+2}\right)^n \cdot 
\left(\frac{3n+2}{3n+1}\right)^n
$$

Comment: $(\cos n-1)$ is *not* changing signs, it always stays negative for $n > 0$. $\cos n$ will be below $0$ infinitely often, so $(\cos n-1)n^2$ is certainly not bounded below, so it does not converge in the strict sense that allows only real values as limits. If $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\cos n-1)n^2 = -\infty$ is actually a question I can't answer.

Comment: Can you please see if I did it correctly? I still don't know what I am supposed to do with the cos*n one, please elaborate.
[first one - please check if it's correct](https://ibb.co/iBr7Q0)
[cosinus one, what next?](https://ibb.co/bEa3Xf)

Comment: @B.Czostek first one is correct, the second limit does not exist because it is not bounded from either side